# Can I exclude standard object fields from a managed package?

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx, metadata-api, standard-objects

I'm trying to migrate metadata from one org to another using a package and the sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve and sfdx force:mdapi:deploy commands.

Account object's Type field is causing a Picklist value not found error (see first four errors in screenshot).

I don't use the Type field anymore so I tried to delete the picklist values but I cannot delete the last one.

And I don't see where Standard Objects / Standard Fields are pulled into my package (e.g. can't see them on package.xml) so I don't know how to exclude this metadata from my package.

Any help - deleting the last picklist value or excluding Type field from my package - would be appreciated.  Thanks!

[image: Picklist value not found]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problematic references appear to be in the Account Record Types `Broker`, `Cedent`, `Other`, and `Reinsurer`. Those record types include references to picklist values that are not being migrated, presumably because your `package.xml` doesn't include `StandardValueSet` metadata for `Account.Type`. Altering the Type field itself in your source org won't fix the problem unless all custom entries are removed.

You can solve the issue by

- removing references to custom picklist entries in the XML metadata for these Record Types;
- removing the Record Types (or the Account object, if applicable) from your package;
- or adding the `StandardValueSet` [`AccountType`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/standardvalueset_names.htm) to your package.

Comment: Thanks, David!  I think all the suggestions you provided would work.  I fixed this by doing something similar to your first bullet.  Since I don't use this field anymore I reset the picklist values to the default picklist values (created a scratch org to find default values and copied them to my org).  Then I repackaged.  This removed the custom picklist entries from my XML file without editing the XML file itself (I used Package Manager to generate a new XML).

Do you know if there's a way to add StandardValueSet from Package Manager?  Or do I need to manually edit the XML to add this?